# jinja2 emplateNotFound (but file exists)

Tags: django, templates, jinja2

In one of my views in **Django 4.0** I want to render a summary of lesson with Jinja2. Even though a template exists for sure in good location I get `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound` which is very confusing.

**views.py:**

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader

def generate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        ...
        var1 = "foo"
        var2 = "bar"
        var3 = 123
        BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
        templatesPath = str(BASE_DIR) + '/static/tex/'
        fileSystemLoader = FileSystemLoader(templatesPath)
        env = Environment(loader = fileSystemLoader)
        renderedLatex = env.get_template(templatesPath + 'lesson_template.tex').render(pvar1, var2, var3)
```

After calling the view the output is:

`jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: /home/user1/Projects/Dramath/Dramath-Project/static/tex/lesson_template.tex`

Just to be sure there is no typo I copied full path to the template file and compared it with the above - both paths are the same.

[image]

For a quick test I tried to relocate `lesson_template.tex` in project root directory but it didin't do much.

Any ideas where might be issue?

Comment: ```tex/rendered/lesson_template.tex``` as opposed to ```tex/lesson_template.tex```?

Comment: The file is in `/static/tex` not in `static/tex/rendered`. Maybe the image was misleading

Comment: ah yes.. my bad.  then could the issue be the ```Dramath``` path being there? since it isn't under that path.  (Not that I can see what is the parent dir of ```Dramath-Project```